# Getting two different results when doing Z inverse transform

Tags: z-transform, inverse-problem

I saw this question was being asked here a few times, but none got actual answer that helped me ( at other Transform of course ).
$$X\left(z\right)=\frac{1-3z^{-1}}{\left(1-0.2z^{-1}\right)\left(1+0.6z^{-1}\right)}$$
If I do by partial fractions, I will receive:
$$X\left(z\right)=-\frac{7}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-0.2z^{-1}}+\frac{9}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+0.6z^{-1}}$$
Final answer by my way:
$$x\left[n\right]=-\frac{7}{2}\cdot \left(0.2\right)^nu\left[n\right]\:-\frac{9}{2}\cdot \left(-0.6\right)^nu\left[-n-1\right]$$
With:
$$ROC\::\:\left\{z\in \mathbb{C}|0.2<\left|z\right|<0.6\right\}$$
But if I will do by other way:
$$X\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1-0.2z^{-1}\right)\left(1+0.6z^{-1}\right)}-\frac{1}{\left(1-0.2z^{-1}\right)\left(1+0.6z^{-1}\right)}\cdot 3z^{-1}$$
And define: $$G\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1-0.2z^{-1}\right)\left(1+0.6z^{-1}\right)}$$
With that, to partial fractions to each function, you will get two expressions for each part.

Final answer This way:
$$x\left[n\right]=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^nu\left[n\right]-\frac{3}{4}\cdot \left(-\frac{5}{3}\right)^nu\left[-n-1\right]-\frac{3}{4}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}u\left[n-1\right]+\frac{9}{4}\cdot \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{n-1}u\left[-n\right]$$
I guess from here you understand what I mean, you will receive different output basically. The inverse will be different.

My question:
Which is the "True" way, why is it the the "True" way, why the other way was not allowed? According to solutions, they did it the other way and thus I got with my partial fractions a bad solution.

EDIT:
Adding proof of my partial fractions:
$$y\left(x\right)=\frac{1-3x}{\left(1-0.2x\right)\left(1+0.6x\right)}\:=\:\frac{A}{1-0.2x}+\frac{B}{1+0.6x},$$
You will get:
$$\:A=-\frac{7}{2},\:B=\frac{9}{2}$$
You can check at symbolab partial fraction calculator \ calculate easily, but its better to check at symbolab.
Just define $z^{-1}=x$ and go with it.

Comment: You appear to have at least a sign mistake in your partial fraction expansion.

Comment: why? if you do partial fraction exepansion as when you call $z^{-1}=x$, you will receive it, I checked also at symbolab

Comment: @AndyWalls Added proof at edit for my partial fractions. look

Comment: My mistake.  Your partial fraction expansion is correct.  You haven't shown the inversion of the Z transforms back to the sample domain, so it is unclear what the difference is about which you are speaking.

Comment: @AndyWalls Hmm, its kind of long to write it at latex, I am a hard writer at latex.
I just know by the solutions, you will get by my Partial fraction expansion 2 expressions for $x[n]$ and if you do partial fractions in the other way, as I said, you will receive 4 expressions for $x[n]$.   
If I have to write the whole way for the answer, it will take me an hour, but actually, I can upload the final answer, I will EDIT

Comment: @AndyWalls Hope the final answer helps, I really can not write the all solutions.

Comment: Both ways are correct, just do the math right, get rid of typos, and simplify to see that both solution are identical.

Comment: Then why am I getting wrong answer? from the $X(Z)$ I reached, I just used known inverse z transform formula and reached the wrong answer. You said to do the math right, so I don't understand where is the mistake.

Comment: The first answer isn't wrong, and the second one just has a few typos. It's straightforward to show the equivalence of both answers. See my answer below.

Comment: Oh I see, I will check  now the answer, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that the ROC is given, because the sequence $x[n]$ is only uniquely defined by $X(z)$ **and** the ROC.

Your first result is correct. Of course, both methods must lead to the same result if done correctly. Your second result is also correct, apart from two typos: the second and the  fourth term should have the pole $-3/5$ in parenthesis (not $-5/3$ and $+3/5$).

Now it only remains to show that the two results are identical. This can be done in a few basic steps. Let's first look at the causal part of the second solution:

\begin{align*}
x_1[n] &= \frac14\left(\frac15\right)^nu[n] - \frac34\left(\frac15\right)^{n-1}u[n-1] \\
&= \frac14\left(\frac15\right)^nu[n] -  \frac34\cdot 5\left(\frac15\right)^{n}u[n] + \frac{15}{4}\delta[n] \\
&=-\frac72\left(\frac15\right)^{n}u[n] + \frac{15}{4}\delta[n]
\end{align*}

In the same way you can rewrite the anti-causal part of the second solution, and you'll see that the term $\frac{15}{4}\delta[n]$ cancels out and the final result is identical to the first solution, which shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: Great answer, Thank you very much!!
This post will help other people too who will have trouble in the future, as seen in other posts, none got really a good answer that fit ( atleast to me ). If I am good with it, probably others who will need it also!!